# Change zoom level 3d scatterPlot (Plotly)

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a 3d scatterplot of which i want to change its zoom level and pan around it programmatically. I have tried setting the range in the layout from the beggining but it does not change the actual zoom level, just the points in the range:

```
"layout": 
{
    margin: {
        l: 0,
        r: 0,
        b: 0,
        t: 0,
        pad: 1
    },
     scene:{
        xaxis: {range:[-13,13.5]},
        yaxis: {range:[-15.5,13.5]},
        zaxis: {range:[-14.5,13.5]},
    }
},
```

Also i've tried invoking it with the relayout function, but it is also not working

```
var update = {
     scene:{
        xaxis: {range:[-13,13.5]},
        yaxis: {range:[-15.5,13.5]},
        zaxis: {range:[-14.5,13.5]},
    },
};
Plotly.relayout(gd, update);
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally i found the property to change the camera position:

```
var update = {
scene:{
          camera: {
          center: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, 
          eye: { x: 2, y: 2, z: 0.1 }, 
           up: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 1 }
            }
        },
};


Plotly.relayout(gd, update);
```